# find lines between two patterns using sed

Tags: sed

I have the lines in text.txt as below:

```
blah blah..
blah abc blah..
blah abc blah
blah blah..
blah blah..
blah blah..
blah efg blah blah
blah blah..
blah abc blah
blah abc blah
blah abc blah
blah abc blah
blah abc blah
blah blah..
blah efg blah blah
blah blah..
blah blah..
```

I want to output the lines between each last occurrence of "abc" before "efg" and "efg", for the above example, I want to output:

```
blah abc blah
blah blah..
blah blah..
blah blah..
blah efg blah blah
blah abc blah
blah blah..
blah efg blah blah
```

I know sed can select ranges using two patterns, like:

```
sed -n '/abc/,/efg/p' test.txt
```

However the output will begin from the first occurrence of "abc" instead of the last one, the output is as following:

```
blah abc blah..
blah abc blah
blah blah..
blah blah..
blah blah..
blah efg blah blah
blah abc blah
blah abc blah
blah abc blah
blah abc blah
blah abc blah
blah blah..
blah efg blah blah
```

Any enhancement can I do on the command line so the output will begin from a last occurrence of "abc"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/\<abc\>/,/\<efg\>/{/\<abc\>/{h;d};H;/\<efg\>/{x;p}}' file
```

Comment: I did some search to understand this, correct me if I'm wrong: 1, escaped angle brackets are optional, which indicate what we are looking for are words. 2, 'h' command means save the pattern space into hold buffer, 'H' means append pattern space into hold buffer, 'x' means exchange pattern space and hold buffer. 3, the whole command will firstly select the ranges beginning with the first line contains 'abc' and ending with the following first line contains 'efg', and then in each range find the last line contain 'abc', and save the lines following till the line contains 'efg', and print them