# how to show lines between two same pattern?

Tags: sed

Hi I want to show lines between two **same pattern.**

I am using this command,

```
sed -n '/WORD1/,/WORD1/p' file.txt
```

This command only works if two pattern are different. But in my case both patterns are same.

So I am not getting proper output.

What is solution?

-----Vishal Patel

Comment: possible duplicate of [find lines between two patterns using sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334032/find-lines-between-two-patterns-using-sed)

Comment: On my mac, it works even if the patterns are the same (Mac has BSD sed by default). I don't have GNU sed so I cannot test it, but I really doubt if it should be any different in this regard.

Comment: @fedorqui: That problem is different, patterns are different and has an additional condition based in context of other text.

Comment: @Birei oh, right, I just retracted my close vote.

Comment: @user2866747, please show both your input and output, and explain why the output is not what you want. This command gives me the expected output (11 lines): `sed -n '/5/,/5/p'< <(seq 10 ; seq 10)`

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.

Here is the content of file.txt

```
outside
WORD1
inside
WORD1
outside
```

And the ouput of your command is

```
WORD1
inside
WORD1
```