# Remove part between two patterns in bash

Tags: sed

Let's say I have a huge file with this:

```
(Ano_gla|EOG091B00FI:0.21327484,Tri_cas|EOG091B00FI:0.14561670,((Tri_bro|EOG091B00FI:0.00523450,Tri_jap|EOG091B00FI:0.01261030)1.00
0000:0.26780267,(((((Orm_nit|EOG091B00FI:0.00243200,Orm_pom|EOG091B00FI:0.00914980)1.000000:0.08747204,(((((Meg_dor|EOG091B00FI:0.0
0953580,Meg_sti|EOG091B00FI:0.02205870)1.000000:0.09005934,(Cer_mar|EOG091B00FI:0.00429740,Cer_sol|EOG091B00FI:0.02112877)1.000000:
0.07852307)0.937000:0.01510878,(((Cec_fun|EOG091B00FI:0.04067119,(Tri_sar|EOG091B00FI:0.00462004,(Nas_gir|EOG091B00FI:0.00126111,Na
s_lon|EOG091B00FI:0.00087461)0.877000:0.00251191)0.995000:0.01752929)1.000000:0.04366313,(Tri_bra|EOG091B00FI:0.00461186,Tri_pre|EO
G091B00FI:0.01023626)1.000000:0.44067486)0.000000:0.01008020,(Ana_pse|EOG091B00FI:0.07264534))
```

And I'm looking for a bash method in order to remove the part between the `|` and `:`

and get:

```
(Ano_gla:0.21327484,Tri_cas:0.14561670,((Tri_bro:0.00523450,Tri_jap:0.01261030)1.00
0000:0.26780267,(((((Orm_nit:0.00243200,Orm_pom:0.00914980)1.000000:0.08747204,(((((Meg_dor:0.0
0953580,Meg_sti:0.02205870)1.000000:0.09005934,(Cer_mar:0.00429740,Cer_sol:0.02112877)1.000000:
0.07852307)0.937000:0.01510878,(((Cec_fun:0.04067119,(Tri_sar:0.00462004,(Nas_gir:0.00126111,Na
s_lon:0.00087461)0.877000:0.00251191)0.995000:0.01752929)1.000000:0.04366313,(Tri_bra:0.00461186,Tri_pre:0.01023626)1.000000:0.44067486)0.000000:0.01008020,(Ana_pse:0.07264534
```

I tried:

```
sed -e 's/\(|\).*\(:\)/\1\2/g' myfile
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Why capture `|` if you want it gone?

Comment: What happened to the `))` at the end of the file?

Comment: Does the input file really contain multiple lines, and if so, does the number of lines in the output matter?

Comment: Should `a|b|c:d` become `a:d` or `a|b:d` or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find lines between two patterns using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334032/find-lines-between-two-patterns-using-sed)

Comment: "Does not work" how? You don't get any replacements? Or it replaces too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/|[^:]*//g' myfile
```

Explained:

```sh
:a           # Label to jump to
$! {         # On every line but the last one
    N        # Append next line to pattern space
    ba       # Jump to label
}
s/|[^:]*//g  # Remove every pipe up to (and excluding) the next colon
```

This slurps the complete file into the pattern space and then does one global substitution.

Notice that this leaves the closing `))` of the input file in place, unlike your expected output.

---

For seds other than GNU sed, the command has to be pulled apart a bit so that the label is separate:

```sh
sed -e ':a' -e '$!{N;ba;}' -e 's/|[^:]*//g' myfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's/|[^|:]*:/:/g' file
(Ano_gla:0.21327484,Tri_cas:0.14561670,((Tri_bro:0.00523450,Tri_jap:0.01261030)1.00
0000:0.26780267,(((((Orm_nit:0.00243200,Orm_pom:0.00914980)1.000000:0.08747204,(((((Meg_dor:0.0
0953580,Meg_sti:0.02205870)1.000000:0.09005934,(Cer_mar:0.00429740,Cer_sol:0.02112877)1.000000:
0.07852307)0.937000:0.01510878,(((Cec_fun:0.04067119,(Tri_sar:0.00462004,(Nas_gir:0.00126111,Na
s_lon:0.00087461)0.877000:0.00251191)0.995000:0.01752929)1.000000:0.04366313,(Tri_bra:0.00461186,Tri_pre|EO
G091B00FI:0.01023626)1.000000:0.44067486)0.000000:0.01008020,(Ana_pse:0.07264534))
```

or if your input really is broken across lines then with GNU sed for `-z`:

```
$ sed -z 's/|[^|:]*:/:/g' file
(Ano_gla:0.21327484,Tri_cas:0.14561670,((Tri_bro:0.00523450,Tri_jap:0.01261030)1.00
0000:0.26780267,(((((Orm_nit:0.00243200,Orm_pom:0.00914980)1.000000:0.08747204,(((((Meg_dor:0.0
0953580,Meg_sti:0.02205870)1.000000:0.09005934,(Cer_mar:0.00429740,Cer_sol:0.02112877)1.000000:
0.07852307)0.937000:0.01510878,(((Cec_fun:0.04067119,(Tri_sar:0.00462004,(Nas_gir:0.00126111,Na
s_lon:0.00087461)0.877000:0.00251191)0.995000:0.01752929)1.000000:0.04366313,(Tri_bra:0.00461186,Tri_pre:0.01023626)1.000000:0.44067486)0.000000:0.01008020,(Ana_pse:0.07264534))
```

Comment: The expected output indicates that there is an occurrence that goes across a newline (output has only 5 lines).

Answer (score 1):

if your data in 'd' file try gnu sed,

```
sed -E 's/\|[^:]+:/:/g' d
```